# What should be the thickness of a glass table top

Tags: glass, table

I want to make my own dining table. I'm planning to buy a glass table top, but I need to know if a glass of 1/4" will be fine for that.

> Condition: Brand new item in box
>
> Shape: Rectangle
>
> Available: Sizes36x60
>
> Glass Type: Clear Glass
>
> Edge Work: Beveled Polish
>
> Corner Finish: Eased
>
> Strength: Tempered

http://www.dullesglassandmirror.com/store/36x60-inch-rectangle-glass-table-top-14-inch-thick-bevel-polished-edge-eased-T36x60RE6MMBETEM-T.aspx

Also I think using a Nano470 Construction Glass Glue for adhering to the base would be fine.

Should I buy a glass with a greater thickness?

Another thing I am asking is how can I illuminate the glass with LED. I see something in this site at the bottom of the page:

http://www.thinkglass.com/glass-countertop-residential/tabletop/tabletop

Would this work?

Comment: Note that glass cannot be cut after it is tempered, so you need to buy the exact size you intend to use.

Comment: I'd avoid gluing, unless the glue has some flex to it. Wood moves, and you could end up with the frame or the glass cracking.

Comment: home depot has a similar size glass available and it is much cheaper. http://www.homedepot.com/p/Peak-Aluminum-Railing-66-in-x-36-5-16-in-x-1-4-in-Tempered-Glass-Panel-50895/203683313

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1/4" **tempered** glass should be fine. It's considerably stronger than the same thickness of normal glass, and also much safer in the event that you do manage to break it.

LED (or any other light source) into a glass sheet is normally injected at the edges (the LEDs being built into the table frame) - but it may not be all that exciting on a clear glass sheet (the ones you linked to were heavily textured - it needs to at least be frosted on one side for much light to get out.)

Comment: 30x60 with no indicated center support (edge support only)? This seems to be risky, even for tempered. Is there an industry guide as to unsupported expanses considered safe?

Comment: Yes it HAS to be tempered.  Better if it were fire rated too for a table top.  Tempered glass will have cost a little $$$ since it has to be cut to specifications before tempering.

Comment: I wouldn't suggest using it for a dance floor - for a table-top it should be fine. I've done quite a bit with 34x76 tempered glass that's generally only 1/8" thick (double-pane patio doors with failed seals so they get fogged up and replaced) and it's tough stuff.

Comment: @bib I'm thinking on a cross table bases o pillars base

Answer (score 1):

1/4" thickness is fine in tempered glass but for more strength and safety you can also use the laminated safety glass for glass table top. you can find laminated safety glass in your required shape and size at

https://www.fabglassandmirror.com/laminated/

Laminated glass table tops are more safer than the clear glass table tops and even from the tempered glass table tops.

You can illuminate the glass table top with LED, i have searched in most of the videos full installation process is available.